# Show a Form behind everything else, and without stealing focus?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

There's an existing question on StackOverflow on how to show a form without stealing focus. The answer is override `ShowWithoutActivation` and return true:

```
protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation
{
  get { return true; }
}
```

This works well enough.

Now i want to go one step further. i want a show a Form (i.e. make it visible), but have it be *behind* other forms in the z-order.

Possible in .net?

If not, possible with P/Invoke?

### Bonus Chatter

Calling `SendToBack()` doesn't work:

```
   RunnerForm frm = new RunnerForm();
// frm.Show();
   frm.Visible = true;
   frm.SendToBack();
```

Comment: well you can make other forms active so that they come over this one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little bit of PInvoke using [SetWindowPos function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
public static class HWND {
  public static readonly IntPtr
  NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2),
  BROADCAST = new IntPtr(0xffff),
  TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1),
  TOP = new IntPtr(0),
  BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);
}

public static class SWP {
  public static readonly int
  NOSIZE = 0x0001,
  NOMOVE = 0x0002,
  NOZORDER = 0x0004,
  NOREDRAW = 0x0008,
  NOACTIVATE = 0x0010,
  DRAWFRAME = 0x0020,
  FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020,
  SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040,
  HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080,
  NOCOPYBITS = 0x0100,
  NOOWNERZORDER = 0x0200,
  NOREPOSITION = 0x0200,
  NOSENDCHANGING = 0x0400,
  DEFERERASE = 0x2000,
  ASYNCWINDOWPOS = 0x4000;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, int uFlags);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  RunnerForm frm = new RunnerForm();
  SetWindowPos(frm.Handle, HWND.BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP.SHOWWINDOW | SWP.NOMOVE | SWP.NOOWNERZORDER | SWP.NOSIZE | SWP.NOACTIVATE);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this is the correct solution. But it's a little strange that `SWP` is a static class rather than an enum. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To add on to [the viable solution Lars provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9335217/366904), you could also prevent the user from ever changing the window's Z order altogether.

To do that, you would override the form's `WndProc` method and catch the [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632653.aspx) that is sent to a window when its size, position, or Z order position is about to change. The super cool thing about this message—I think it's one of my favorites—is that it actually allows you to *change* or modify the parameters of the change that is about to take place.

So in this case, you'll want to set the `SWP_NOZORDER` flag to prevent the window's Z order from being changed.

The notable thing about this approach is that it will always maintain your window in the Z order at the last position you left it. The user won't be able to bring it to the front, which may or may not be a good thing, depending on how your UI is designed. It will also work just fine with controls other than forms.

Sample code pulled from one of my libraries:

```
internal class NativeMethods
{
    public const int WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 0x46;
    public const int WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED = 0x47;

    [Flags()]
    public enum SetWindowPosFlags
    {
        SWP_NOSIZE = 0x1,
        SWP_NOMOVE = 0x2,
        SWP_NOZORDER = 0x4,
        SWP_NOREDRAW = 0x8,
        SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x10,
        SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x20,
        SWP_DRAWFRAME = SWP_FRAMECHANGED,
        SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x40,
        SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x80,
        SWP_NOCOPYBITS = 0x100,
        SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = 0x200,
        SWP_NOREPOSITION = SWP_NOOWNERZORDER,
        SWP_NOSENDCHANGING = 0x400,
        SWP_DEFERERASE = 0x2000,
        SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS = 0x4000,
    }

    public enum WindowZOrder
    {
        HWND_TOP = 0,
        HWND_BOTTOM = 1,
        HWND_TOPMOST = -1,
        HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2,
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct WINDOWPOS
    {
        public IntPtr hWnd;
        public IntPtr hwndInsertAfter;
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public int cx;
        public int cy;
        public SetWindowPosFlags flags;

        // Returns the WINDOWPOS structure pointed to by the lParam parameter
        // of a WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING or WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED message.
        public static WINDOWPOS FromMessage(Message msg)
        {
            // Marshal the lParam parameter to an WINDOWPOS structure,
            // and return the new structure
            return (WINDOWPOS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(msg.LParam, typeof(WINDOWPOS));
        }

        // Replaces the original WINDOWPOS structure pointed to by the lParam
        // parameter of a WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING or WM_WINDOWPSCHANGING message
        // with this one, so that the native window will be able to see any
        // changes that we have made to its values.
        public void UpdateMessage(Message msg)
        {
            // Marshal this updated structure back to lParam so the native
            // window can respond to our changes.
            // The old structure that it points to should be deleted, too.
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(this, msg.LParam, true);
        }
    }
}
```

And then I have a slick little subclassed form that raises .NET events corresponding to these messages and allows the event handler to modify the values or cancel the event if desired. I don't handle `SWP_NOZORDER`, but you can get an idea of how it might work.

```
public class FormEx : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    // ...snip constructors and such          

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case NativeMethods.WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
                this.WmWindowPosChanging(m);
                return;
            // ...snip
        }

        base.WndProc(m);
    }

    private void WmWindowPosChanging(ref Message m)
    {
        // Extract the WINDOWPOS structure corresponding to this message
        NativeMethods.WINDOWPOS wndPos = NativeMethods.WINDOWPOS.FromMessage(m);

        // Determine if the size is changing (absence of SWP_NOSIZE flag)
        if (!((wndPos.flags & NativeMethods.SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOSIZE) == NativeMethods.SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOSIZE))
        {
            // Raise the LowLevelSizeChanging event
            SizeChangingEventArgs e = new SizeChangingEventArgs(this.Size, new Size(wndPos.cx, wndPos.cy));
            this.OnLowLevelSizeChanging(e);

            // Determine if the user canceled the size changing event
            if (e.Cancel)
            {
                // If so, add the SWP_NOSIZE flag
                wndPos.flags = wndPos.flags | NativeMethods.SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOSIZE;
                wndPos.UpdateMessage(m);
            }
        }

        // Determine if the position is changing (absence of SWP_NOMOVE flag)
        if (!((wndPos.flags & NativeMethods.SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOMOVE) == NativeMethods.SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOMOVE))
        {
            // Raise the LowLevelPositionChanging event
            PositionChangingEventArgs e = new PositionChangingEventArgs(this.Location, new Point(wndPos.x, wndPos.y));
            this.OnLowLevelPositionChanging(e);

            // Determine if the user canceled the position changing event
            if (e.Cancel)
            {
                // If so, add the SWP_NOMOVE flag
                wndPos.flags = wndPos.flags | NativeMethods.SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOMOVE;
                wndPos.UpdateMessage(m);
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(m);
    }

    // ...snip event infrastructure
}
```

<sub>**Edit:** Hmm, this code was originally written in VB.NET and I ran it through an automatic translator. It looks like the `ref`s didn't get properly inserted everywhere that they should be when making function calls. Follow the urging of the compiler to fix it...</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
RunnerForm frm = new RunnerForm();
myMainForm.Owner = frm;
```

Comment: @CodyGray Perhaps by having *two* problems, the first problem will seem to disappear!

Comment: This will set RunnerForm's instance to be the parent of the main form, which will put it behind the main form in the Z-order - as requested.